# Spring WebClient throws javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLEngine closed already when used heavily

Tags: netty, spring-webflux, sslengine

That's my code:

```
WebClient.create().post()
                .uri(URI.create(url))
                .header("Authorization",
                        "Basic " + Base64Utils.encodeToString(("username:password").getBytes(UTF_8)))
                .body(Mono.just(requestBody), Object.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(responseType)
```

I call this function from multiple threads at the same time. 
When I only call it around 20~30 times in a single run it works perfectly fine. But when I call it 500~600 times in around 2 minutes (to the same URL) it throws

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLEngine closed already
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(...)(Unknown Source)
```

**EDIT**

I've tried creating only one instance of `WebClient` but it still throws the same exception

Comment: did you fix this?

Comment: that's my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53181640/1525867 
I've used some other client

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out this is happening due to this issue https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/413

To resolve it you need to create `WebClient` like that:

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
               .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(options -> {
                   options.poolResources(PoolResources.fixed("httpPool")).compression(true);
               })).build();
```

you can change the pool size by calling `PoolResources.fixed` with its second parameter

Another solution is to replace this Async http client with another one like this one https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client

Comment: We are using async-http-client (through the Play framework) and we still get the exception.  But we are using nginx as a reverse proxy doing SSL termination.    I think the issue still comes up with sufficient load.

Comment: Is it fixed by now? After heavy load with newest release of spring webflux (5.1.7) I got the same exception with huuuge stacktrace.

Comment: I don't think this is fixed.  I see this all the time on spring webflux 5.3.4.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `WebClient.create()` repeatedly creates and initializes HTTP resources multiple times.

Without more details about this particular issue or a complete stacktrace, it's hard to pinpoint the exact problem here. But I suspect that creating a client HTTP connector for each call is wasteful and might cause issues with setting up SSL on the client side.

You could try instead:

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();
// then in your for loop
webClient.post() //...
```

If you're using Spring Boot, you should instead inject a `WebClient.Builder` instance and use it to create a `WebClient` instance.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue, like the OP mentioned it happens under load but also it is easily triggered by an "nginx -s reload" while the server is under load.  I posted this on the nginx forum but had no replies so far https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,281786.  In my case I am using a singleton client instance for the multiple requests, so I don't think [Brian's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22982/brian-clozel) comment applies.